# limit YouTube time

Tags: youtube, clock

My son watches YouTube on his phone all the time.  I'd like to limit him to 1 hour a day on YouTube.  I know there's a YouTube kids app, that allows you to set a timer, but I don't mind him having access to the full YouTube. I just want to limit his time.

Is there a way to set a timer on the full YouTube app?  I was thinking perhaps a proxy server runs on the phone that cuts off connection to youtube.com after a certain amount of time, but maybe there are other ideas.

I could deal with this issue via Good Parenting, but I prefer to just automate things if possible.

Comment: Several [Child protection](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/childprotect) apps offer to restrict app access in that way, letting you chose apps to completely block, block but allow in a certain window, or give time-limited access regardless of daytime.

Comment: My router has similar functionality if you aren't set on an app based solution.

Comment: maybe this will help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzqhiAxQG_Q
better late then never